# Hiding and showing fields based on menu item

Tags: module, menu, administrator, module-params

I have a module with a few text input fields. For example:

```
menu a
menu b
```

I also have two menu types, each for different sections of the site. Is it possible based on which menu type the module is assigned to to determine which field is shown in the Joomla admin?

Comment: Why? What are you using the distinction for?

Comment: Based on the way modules are designed and the purpose they serve, I don't think this is possible. Something close to this is to develop a dynamic module, that will display content based on the page/menu item it is displayed and relative settings to manipulate module behavior in the backend. What do you have in mind though?

Comment: @DavidFritsch, we're using it to configure our desktop and mobile sites separately. We don't currently have a responsive mobile site, so its kind of like we're running two sites from the same admin.

Answer (score 2):

You can detect the Browser (mobile or not) to show the fields. For example: Android, Blackberry, IE Mobile, iPad, iPhone, iPod Touch, NetFront, Nokia, Opera Mini, Opera Mobile, UC Browser.

You can find a handy detection routine in NoNumber's Advanced Module Manager.

Comment: Sorry, the browser doesn't actually matter to me. My question is specific to the joomla administrator. If you rename the menus 'menu a' and 'menu b', for 'menu a' I need the 'menu a' param to be visible in the administrator tool, for 'menu b' I need the 'menu b' param. Is that possible?

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear what you are looking for... you can detect the current menu, and load menu parameters from the module

Comment: Could you expand on this a  little more, I don't see the problem as answered above, with admin backend or otherwise. Maybe a better example of what you are trying to achieve.